# Laravel checkbox is not submitted to controller

Tags: php, laravel, checkbox, input

I have a simple form in a view like this:

```
<form action="{{ URL::route('admin.x') }}" method="POST">
    <input type="text" value="b" name="title" />
    <input type="text" value="c" name="type" />
    <input type="text" value="d" name="postfix" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="ss" />
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form>
```

I used

```
dd(Input::all());
```

for checking all of values posted to controller from view. the result is like below and I want to know how to post checkbox value with form.

> array:4 [▼
>
> "title" => ""
>
> "type" => ""
>
> "postfix" => ""
>
> "_token" => "kSM3pO11KOOWQcCx4PeWcbi4r4AsFx0rSGQoVFtG"
>
> ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A checkbox input is not submitted to the server side script if not checked by the user or by a client side script. So, in these cases, the input isn't sent to your controller

In laravel, if you want to 'normalize' somehow the situation when the input isn't sent, you can create a field by yourself:

```
$data = Input::all();

if ( ! isset($data['check']) )
    $data['check'] = false;
```

Comment: You mean if the checkbox checked by user, it will be appear in dd(Input::all()) result?

Comment: yes, if you check the checkbox you'll see in your example: `"check" => "ss"` as `ss` is the value you assigned to that input

Comment: but it didn't happen as you say.

Comment: @MahmoodKohansal : what is the result of `dd(Input::all());` when you check the checkbox ?

Comment: exactly like when it doesn't ckecked.

Comment: @MahmoodKohansal : in this case there should be something else preventing the value to be submitted, but i can't figure out what it is. Maybe you can try another 'test' page with another form, to see if the checkbox are submitted

Comment: thanks, its working for me...just one little thing...there is a ")" missing after if statement

Answer (score 3):

You can ensure that your server side receives a value for the checkbox, regardless of whether it was checked, by creating a hidden input field with the same name **above** the checkbox field.

This way, if the form is submitted without the checkbox being checked, the server side will receive the value from the hidden input field whereas if the checkbox is checked the server will receive the checked value due to the field being lower in the form.

`<input type="hidden" name="checkbox" value="0"/>
 <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="ss"/>`

Answer (score 0):

This returns true if the checkbox is checked, false if not.

```
Input:has('check')
```

Comment: No difference to check it or not! maybe something is wrong but it returned me false anyway.